# How to emulate gps using network location in the android Emulator?

Tags: android, testing, location

I have test using gps location and success. But now i want to test using network location. 
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse and the AVD Emulator do the following:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other
Android -> Emulator Control
```

This will open a tab in the IDE that will give you all the controls to interface with your running emulator.